# How to make methods from parent class use a different variable?

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have a class like this:

```
class A {
protected:
    class Node {
    public:
        int x;
        Node* next;
    };

    Node* root;
    .
    .
    .
};
```

And a lot of methods using this "root".

Now, say I want to inherit from A class, and make all the methods use a "better" node. Something like:

```
class B : public A{
    class NewNode : public A::Node{
    public:
        int y;
    };

    NewNode* root;
    .
    .
    .
};
```

Is there a way of doing something like this? And if not, what are the alternatives (beside rewriting A class)?

Thank you!

Comment: You can consider CRTP http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern or anyhow pass NewNode as a template parameter to A

Comment: Inheriting from A makes your class have a member named root already, Does NewNode and Node inherit from same class ?

Comment: One way would be to have an interface (class with pure virtual functions only) that would have all the public functions of `A`. Then both `A` and `B` would implement this interface and would both be free to implement it in any way they want. If needed then same could be done for the class `Node`. It all depends how you use `root` and how you use classes `A` and `B` in your code and what you want to achieve.

Comment: Sorry, i Didn't see that part in the code, can you show where do you use the member root ? Normally, since `newNode` inherits from `Node`, you can put  a `NewNode` in `A::root`

Comment: You should be able to use NewNode as the root. It is derived from Node. How to get root to point to the NewNode really depends on how you create the Node in A. Do you have a factory method to create a Node? Than maybe you can override that method in B and let the factory method return a NewNode. You defintely do not need a new root field in B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `NewNode` is derived from `Node` you can put something like this in the `B` constructor

```
delete root;  //remove the Node
root = new NewNode();  //and put in the better one
```

More realistically, you'll probably need something like this

```
Node * oldRoot = root;
root = new NewNode(oldRoot);
delete oldRoot;
```

You don't need a new variable in B, just use `A::root`.

Comment: Thank you! 
I think I will use this method, but I have some member functions in A that allocate more Nodes. I will add something like factory method to create Nodes in A, and override it in B to create NewNode (as Hauke S mentioned). Is it the right to do what I want?

Answer (score 0):

If A is abstract, it can be compiled and used  with all its methods independently from any derived classes. Therefore, code that accesses this variable will already be generated and cannot change. I think there is really no way to do what you want to do, without modifying A.

Although, it depends a little bit, what exactly you mean. If NewNode is derived from Node and Node has virtual functions, A will of course call the methods of NewNode. If you don't want NewNode to be derived from Node, you probably have to make A a template class. This would also work, if A accesses members of Node directly, instead of using virtual Getter/Setter-Functions.